# String must contain multiple words

Tags: python, string, parsing

I'm new to Python and I have a question.

I am making a simple chatbot and I want it to give answers to questions and things like that.

Here is an example:

```
def ChatMode():
    ChatCommand = raw_input ("- user: ")
    if "quit" in ChatCommand :
        print "Lucy: See you later."
        print ""
        UserCommand()
    else :
        print "Lucy: sorry i don\'t know what you mean."
        ChatMode()
```

For something more advanced I need it to check for 2 strings.

I tried some things like:

```
  def ChatMode() :
      ChatCommand = raw_input ("- user: ")
      if "quit" + "now" in ChatCommand :
          print "Lucy: See you later."
          print ""
          UserCommand()
      else :
          print "Lucy: sorry i don\'t know what you mean."
          ChatMode()
```

But that made `"quitnow"`.

I also tried to replace the `+` with an `&` but that gave me an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Does anyone have a short code to do this? I don't want 5+ sentences, I want to keep it as short as possible.

Comment: You're looking for: `if "quit" in CharCommand and "now" in CharCommand:`.

Comment: as a side note, i don't know if this is just a short homework project, or a serious thing, but if it's the latter, consider looking into nltk: http://www.nltk.org/

Answer (score 2):

Use separate clauses to check if both `"quit"` and `"now"` are in the `ChatCommand` e.g.

```
if "quit" in ChatCommand and "now" in ChatCommand:
```

Note that in Python, the [logical and operator](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Flogande.htm) && is `and`, and `&` is the [bitwise and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

Answer (score 1):

```
if "quit" in ChatCommand and "now" in ChatCommand:
```

Also, as a bit of style, in Python `CamelCase` is usually reserved for `Class`es.

Answer (score 1):

Use `all()`:

```
if all(word in ChatCommand for word in ("quit", "now")):
```

If you want to avoid matching `quit` within `quite`, you can use a regex:

```
import re
if all(re.search(regex, ChatCommand) for regex in (r"\bquit\b", r"\bnow\b")):
```

because the `\b` [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) only match at the start and end of a word.

Comment: Will this solution, in the worst case, look through `ChatCommand` twice? Is there a (clean and easy) way to only look through it once comparing both instead?

Comment: Yes, and I don't see how that could be avoided elegantly. You *could* do a single regex search, but under the hood, that would also have to scan the string twice, I suppose.